# Java Client/Server reading and writing doesn't work and no error

Tags: java, string, client-server, utf

Client.java

```
package Client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client {
        /*
     To send string to server use "out.print(data)"
     To use info sent from server use "in.readLine()"
     */
    int port = 1234;
    String hostname = "localhost";
    String input,output;

    public void send(String text) {
    try {
         Socket skt = new Socket(hostname, port);           /*Connects to server*/

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));          /*Reads from server*/
         System.out.println("Server:" + in.readLine());

         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.print(text);                                   /*Writes to server*/

         skt.close();
         out.close();    /*Closes all*/
         in.close();
      }

      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error Connecting to Server\n");
      } 
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     Client c = new Client();
     c.send("Server is online");    //sends message to server
   }
}
```

Server.java

```
package Server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    /*
     To send string to client use "out.print(data)"
     To use info sent from client use "in.readLine()"
     */
        int port = 1234;
    String input,output;

    public void send(String text) {
    try {
         ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(port);
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();                    /*Waiting for Connection from client*/
         System.out.print("Server has connected!\n");

         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.print(text);                                                  /*Write/Send to Client*/

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));                   /*Read from Client*/
         System.out.println("Client:" + in.readLine());

         out.close();
         in.close();
         skt.close();               /*Closes all*/
         srvr.close();
      } catch( Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error Connecting\n");
      } 
    }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Server s = new Server();
       s.send("Client is online");  //sends a message to client

   }
}
```

why does nothing apart from
`Server has connected!`
happen when on both I have sent from the server and client

```
s.send("X is online");
```

which should be read on the other side and printed out in the cmd?

(is it because the bufferreader is activated after printwriter and doesn't pick it up? if so how can I fix this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `BufferedReader#readLine` call will block indefinitely unless you send a newline character. Replace

```
out.print(text);
```

with

```
out.println(text);
```

to match the `BufferedReader#readLine` calls from both client & server.

Comment: That should have fixed your problem though, no?

Comment: Strange, tested here and worked fine. Try cleaning your project & rerun.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility - look at the ordering here:

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
 out.print(text);

 skt.close();
 out.close();
```

You're closing the *socket* before you close the *writer*. That means if the writer has any buffered data, it has no chance to write it. Try switching round the order in which you close things - close the socket as the *last* thing.

(Normally you'd have these in a `finally` block, mind you...)

EDIT: And then I noticed that you're not printing a *line* on the server side. You should make *both* changes.

Comment: I tried switching them around on both classes so skt is last and writer first and it makes no difference, also when I put them in a finally block they cannot find the symbols "out.,in.,srvr." etc.

Comment: @String.userName: Well you can't just put them in a finally block with no other work... but you *should* make sure you close everything even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: fair enough i've never used finally blocks before and wouldn't have known

Answer (score 1):

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client {
        /*
     To send string to server use "out.print(data)"
     To use info sent from server use "in.readLine()"
     */
    int port = 1234;
    String hostname = "localhost";
    String input,output;

    public void send(String text) {
    try {
         Socket skt = new Socket(hostname, port);           /*Connects to server*/

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));          /*Reads from server*/
         System.out.println("Server:" + in.readLine());

         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.println(text);                                   /*Writes to server*/
         out.close();    /*Closes all*/
         in.close();
         skt.close();

      }

      catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error Connecting to Server\n");
      } 
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     Client c = new Client();
     c.send("Server is online");    //sends message to server
   }
}
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    /*
     To send string to client use "out.print(data)"
     To use info sent from client use "in.readLine()"
     */
        int port = 1234;
    String input,output;

    public void send(String text) {
    try {

        ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(port);
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();                    /*Waiting for Connection from client*/
         System.out.println("Server has connected!\n");

         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.println(text);                                                  /*Write/Send to Client*/

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));                   /*Read from Client*/
         System.out.println("Client:" + in.readLine());

       out.close();
         in.close();
         skt.close();              /*Closes all*/
        srvr.close();
      } catch( Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error Connecting\n");
      } 
    }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Server s = new Server();
       s.send("Client is online");  //sends a message to client

   }
}
```

Above code is working for me 
See if you missed anything

Comment: I swapped your client version with mine and there was no change but when I swap your server with mine it works! however the only difference between them is a newline under "try {" and a space before "ServerSocket skt..." I have no idea what the problem was :O