# Java - TCP/IP - Server can't send message back to Client?

Tags: java, tcp

I want to send an object from my client to my localhost server to add to database, and send result back whether the object was sent successfully or not. The object was sent successfully, but my server doesn't send the result back to client, and causes my client frame form hanged due to waiting for response from server. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can you tell me some ways to fix this?

Here is the function to send the result:

```
public void sendResult(String result) {
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = myServer.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to client");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        os.writeObject(result);
        System.out.println("Result sent");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where the send result function is called:

```
public void service() {
    try {
        if (receiveStudent() != null) {
            Student std = receiveStudent();
            if (dao.addStudent(std)) {
                System.out.println("OK");
                sendResult("OK");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAILED");
                sendResult("FAILED");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In addition, in the Service function, the console printed "OK", which means the if condition was satisfied.

receive student method:

```
public Student receiveStudent() {
    Student s = new Student();

    try {
        Socket clientSocket = myServer.accept();
        System.out.println("Connect to client successfully");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        Object o = ois.readObject();
        if (o instanceof Student) {
            s = (Student) o;
            return s;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Show your code for ReceiveStudent() method

Comment: The `sendResult()` method waits for a client to connect to it, because of `accept()`. It should be the other way around, the server should connect to the client.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens which means I have to reconnect the client to the server again?

Comment: @BrotherEye you should reuse the `clientSocket` you obtain in `receiveStudent()` to send a response back.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens I have noticed your comment and add a client socket as an attribute of the server class to be a global variable and it works now. Thanks a lot! But now I have to reenter the form twice to add object successfully. Is that some kind of delay or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `myServer.accept()` in `sendResult()`, the server is again waiting for an incoming client connection while this already happened in `receiveStudent()`. Reuse that connection.

Share the client socket you've obtained in `receiveStudent()` by, e.g., turning it into a field.

```
public Student receiveStudent() {
    ...

    try {
        clientSocket = myServer.accept();
        ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and then reuse that socket in `sendResult()` to send the result to the client.

```
public static void sendResult(String result) {
    try {
        ...
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed your comment above about this solution and done it and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't 'want the server to connect to the client'. The *client* connects to the *server*. The server *accepts* connections *from* the client. Answer is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP you are right. Changed that bit, it was badly written.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a String as object why don't you just use something like this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); //for sending String messages
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); //for getting String messages
```

... and then when you need to send you do it like this:

```
out.println(textToServer");  // send to server - don't forget LN in println.
out.flush(); // to clean buffer
```

It should do what you need to be done. 
And make sure that your client class is waiting to get that `InputStream` you're sending, don't forget that, since maybe it's the problem in the Client side. 
Maybe Client is not accepting that incoming `Socket` regardless if it's `ObjectInputStream` or `BufferedReader` that will accept the incoming socket object.

You could provide us a Client class so we can see if there's missing acceptance of incoming socket.

At the end of the method make sure you close your streams and sockets.

```
out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721426/java-client-server-reading-and-writing-doesnt-work-and-no-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165006/simple-java-client-server-program) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256518/socket-program-to-send-and-receive-user-defined-objects-not-working). I hope I was helpful :)

Comment: That's a good idea. But I think my problem is the connection between the server socket and the client socket. If they're not connected then no matter what method you use to send the data, none of them receive. I've made the client socket a global variable instead of creating a local one in the sendResult method and it works now.

Comment: Then have you checked your connection between server and socket?
When you're setting up your server with ServerSocket and accepting clients, are you connecting with your client to the server with correct port? 
`ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);` <br />
`Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);` <br /> Can you please provide us whole code or just Server and Client classes?

Comment: I'm sure to you that they're connected on the right host and port. I think I've accidently connected my server socket to a client socket other than the one I wanted to connect by creating a new client socket in the send result method.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `accept()` twice. This is meaningless. You need to:

1. Accept the connection. This returns a `Socket`.
2. Read the request and create the response.
3. Send the response, via the same `Socket` you accepted at (1).

You *also* want to create a new thread per accepted socket, and you also want to do all I/O in that thread, *including* creating the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Otherwise your server isn't properly multi-threaded and multi-client.

Comment: Thanks! I've turned the client socket to global variable and problem solved